# Stroke adding size to an object

Tags: stroke

I know this happens in indesign where i would create a 3"x3" object and when i add a stroke it becomes 3.0139x3.0139. I know the shape is still the same, but is there a way i can disable this and have it still read 3x3?

Answer (score 3):

In *Transform* or control panel in context menu there's an option <kbd>Dimensions Include Stroke Weight</kbd>. Turn it off to get object dimensions without stroke width.